# Css How to remove blank lines

Tags: css

How can I remove empty lines with css?

I want to ignore the  `<br>`s in the text

Comment: I wonder how they come up with such questions. Please provide more details.

Comment: Define "blank line" (and/or "empty line") and "remove."

Comment: @David @ Sarfraz what else could it mean.i mean <br> i dont want to skip lines

Comment: Then remove those <br> from your HTML code...

Comment: @Capsule -_- im not asking how to press delete on my keyboard

Comment: Yes you do. If you don't, you should seriously ask yourself why you want to keep these extra <br>s.

Comment: @Capsule theyre returned in a bean in that format with linebreaks to be used in other places on the page and the application, so i dont want to mess with that. im asking this because i want to use that info in a popup but without the spaces

Comment: Ah, thank you! This is the first useful information you dare giving us. I still don't understand why you wanted to use the style attribute if you can't touch the HTML but as I said, applying a display:none on <br>s looks like the best option you have.

Answer (score 5):

Funny question...

```
br {display: none;}
```

;-)

Comment: How do you put that in to  style=" "

Comment: @Dave819: You put it in your external style sheet which the page references or a `<style>` tag in the page header.  Try not to put the style in the actual markup, they should be separated.

Comment: I just got upvoted on that one and noticed that comment. Adding an inline style in the markup would mean you have access to the markup and would be able to just remove the <br>, ahah.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to remove whitespace created using `<br />` tags then I don't believe that this can be done using CSS.

You could use JavaScript to remove the whitespace, however the most elegant solution would be to create whitespace using CSS in the first place using margins and padding.

Comment: Well, there's always `br {display: none;}` but I doubt that's what he actually has in mind in his terribly vague question...

Comment: @David Great point! Egg on my face!

Comment: It's kind of a silly question in the first place.  There may be a good reason behind it, but that reason wasn't conveyed.